# Video calling options

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, video-calling

I don't see full support for video calling in my Samsung galaxy S.

1. I am not able to set a direct shortcut for video calling.
2. Not able to disable self image when video calling so that able to see full screen image of the caller.
3. No option to video call directly from logs. Need to go to the contact screen every time.

Is there any app that has better support for video calling?

**Edit:**

I am looking for more features in the video calling facility provided by sim provider (Airtel). I am not interested in video calling via internet like google talk/skype as I don't have internet connectivity all the time.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different options for video calling. i do not know how many of them will support the options you want, but i will try to specify their uses as best i can.

The new version of [Google Talk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1056793)

It supports video calling and handles it well. You have to call from within the app though, i don't believe there is built in platform support for calling from call logs.

[Fring](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fring&feature=search_result)

This is a widely used, multi-platform video chat app that has many options, and i know it allows you to remove your self image, group chat, and it pulls from your contact list to give you a list of other Fring users. On occasion, it has worked with Skype (mobile-to-desktop), but in my experience, this has been spotty.

[Qik](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qik.android&feature=related_apps)

The advantage to Qik is it's incredible online support. It has been improved greatly since it's introduction to the mobile market.

[Tango](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sgiggle.production&feature=related_apps)

This got the last spot because it is personally my least favorite. You can only call to other devices using Tango, which i find extremely limiting, but it is the same scenario for Qik, so it'll have to be dealt with. It has very positive reactions from users though, so it's worth a look.

i hope this helps you get a jump start on finding a solution to what you want. Take a test run with one or a few of these and let us know what works best for you!

Comment: Note that Google Talk only officially supports video on Nexus S phones (as well as Honeycomb devices), so it could be a little buggy on other devices.

Comment: @eldarerathis is correct. But on a good note, i've had it installed on my Evo(rooted) for about two weeks now, and the only crash i get is when i try to use the rear facing camera, which isn't really useful for videochat anyways :P

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for internet based video calling. I am looking for more features in my phone to support the default video calling facility provided by my sim provider.

Comment: @balki, chances are that the features you wish to have will only come as the result of a custom ROM and a root. Beside these, there is generally no way to change or add system functions.

Answer (score 0):

For #3, tap the caller image in the log, and select the second shortcut for video call. If i remember correctly, this has been available since Froyo (2.2), but I'm not sure (running Darky's Rom 10.1, which is 2.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

New skype version has excellent video call quality.

The official version doesn't support video on galaxy S yet, though.
So you need to install the hacked version (check [here](http://androidos.in/2011/07/skype-android-app-patched-to-make-video-calls-on-samsung-galaxy-s-s2/)).

I've been using it on my Samsung Galaxy S and it rocks.