# How can I make a 3G-324M video call?

Tags: 3g, htc-incredible-s, video-calling

I tried to place a [3G-324M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G-324M) video call to my Incredible, but the other phone says that mine doesn't support it.

On the web I found someone mentioned that Incredibles do not support video calls in 3G at all. Others mention that this is possible with Skype.

**The question is** - can I make my phone use 3G video calls without using a mobile Internet (as I think Skype is using Internet rather than native 3G video calls, thus I am paying for mobile Internet with Skype calls and not per rate specified per minute for 3G itself).

Or is Skype the only available option?

Comment: Android doesn't currently support this, as far as I know. It was previously discussed here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11559/video-calling-options and here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10092/questions-regarding-receiving-3g-calls-on-my-ideos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now I don't know of any Android phone capable of establishing 3G-324M Video calls. Android have some parts of 3G-324M implemented in the communications stack, but is far from being complete.

All the android phones that can make “video calls” use Internet.

Given the fact that carriers charge an “extra” for a video call using 3G-324M and that any internet traffic is probably included in your data plan, Android will probably continue to go the way of internet video calls, not 3G-324M.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My mobile operator charges the same amount for 1 MB of Internet traffic as for 1 minute of voice (3G video) call, thus I suppose native 3G video call would be cheaper than using the mobile Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Android does not support Video calls via 3G-324M. [But the Galaxy S, Galaxy S2 and maybe other seem to support it (via TouchWiz)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17567486&postcount=5). At least I have a video call button in the default Galaxy S dialer, that does 3G Video calls.