# How to make 3G Video Calls?

Tags: 3g, video-calling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a 3G-324M video call?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15388/how-can-i-make-a-3g-324m-video-call)

Before people start telling me to use Skype or GTalk, let me make it clear: 3G Video Call is a native value-added-service for video calls based on minutes rather than data plan. It is provided by operators in many countries (except US). Even many Samsung phones do have the 3G Video call option in their "custom" ROM in my country. But I am on a Nexus S and there is currently no built-in way I can use my video "minutes".  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here.  If you're looking for general resources and discussion you would be better off somewhere like XDA since [SO] requires specific questions, like us.

Comment: @MatthewRead, this nothing to challenge, but just curious to know how this is a development related question?

Comment: @Narayanan Check out the original version before my edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this, unless the device manufacturer has added this into their ROM's.

This isn't available in *any* custom ROM, and the implementation of it in Android is somewhat limited, and far from complete.

I believe that Google decided that as they are using an Android, they would have large internet bundles, and therefore it would be cheaper to use internet video calling, so they haven't been implementing 3G video calling (at least not at any great speed).